# Debug Assertion failed!!! error using DoModal

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm new to C++ and MFC programming (using VS2005). I'm trying to use [CFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cfiledialog-class?view=vs-2019#cfiledialog). Here is my code:

```
void CsampleDlg::StopRfWrite()
 {

    if (pFile != NULL)
        fclose(pFile);

    pFile = NULL;

    char dir[512];
    GetCurrentDirectoryA(512, dir);
    CString connected=CString(dir) + _T("\\");
    CString conn = connected + fn;

    TCHAR szFilters[]= _T("RF data file (*.bin)|*.bin||");

    CFileDialog fileDlg(FALSE, _T("bin"), fn,
    OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_HIDEREADONLY, szFilters);

    // Display the file dialog. When user clicks OK, fileDlg.DoModal() 
    // returns IDOK.

    if(fileDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        CString pathName = fileDlg.GetPathName(); 
        CString fileName = fileDlg.GetFileTitle();

        SetWindowText(fileName);

        MoveFile(conn,pathName);
    }
    else
    {
        DeleteFile(conn);
    }
}
```

and receive 
Debug Assertion failed error; (Line 384 in wincore.cpp) it is invoked by fileDlg.DoModal() call. It is random, sometimes program run fine.

Call Stack indicates the following row:

> `ASSERT(pWnd != NULL);`

Comment: Probably unrelated, but I'd expect you to pass `this` as the 6th parameter to the CFileDialog constructor, thereby providing it a parent window.

Comment: What is `fn` and what does it contain?

Comment: What is your character set? (right click on the project in the solution explorer, then chose Properties and look on the "Character Set" option under Advanced). Also you should consider upgrading to VS2019, VS2005 is getting a bit old now.

Comment: Thank you acraig5075. The problem was solved.

Comment: It's a pity you didn't provide an answer explaining what was actually wrong.... You can answer your own question.

Comment: @acr: Not a parent, but an owner. MFC - unfortunately - get's the terminology wrong more often than not. [Window Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features) explains, what they are, respectively.